# How to fetch value from string being returned from responsestream

Tags: c#, string

I have the following code

```
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
}
```

And the responseStr has the value `<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">cb8fbc96-05c6-4b9f-a64d-91a2d357c398</string>`

I would like to fetch this value alone cb8fbc96-05c6-4b9f-a64d-91a2d357c398.

Any help much appreciated...Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're looking for an XML parser.

Comment: Agree with @SLaks. Load the result in `XmlDocument` or `XmlElement`and read the value out.

Comment: @Orphid: No; `XElement` is much easier.

Comment: @SLaks sorry, you're right. I mean't `XElement`. @curiousDev - using the `XElement` class from the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace will be simpler.

Comment: Orphid : thank you. I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems on your client-side, it send a header to specific xml format as result.

There are several ways to do. If you could control your client-side, just set:

```
Content-Type=text/plain
```

If you can't control your client-side, another fairly easy way is to use reg-expression to get rid of those XML tags.

```
String patternXMLTag = @"<[^>]*>";
Regex XMLpattern = new Regex(PatternXMLTag, RegexOption.Compiled);
string result = Regex.Replace(val, patternXMLTag, string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
//result is what you want
return result;
```

Of course, Microsoft provide XmlDocument and XmlElementand class helps you grab data out from a beauty formatted document. You could use them to easily grab data you want.